# vector of weights

Tags: confidence-interval, model-averaging

I am using the MuMIn package for model averaging. However, I am not clear of the function par.avg(). In this function, we need to specify the following,

```
par.avg(x, se, weight, df = NULL, level = 1 - alpha, alpha = 0.05,
revised.var = TRUE, adjusted = TRUE)
```

x: vector of parameters.
se: vector of standard errors.
weight: vector of weights.

I am using the regression coefficient (beta) for x, standard error obtained after model averaging and the Akaike weight of the parameter (predictor). However, I find that irrespective of the Akaike weight value I input, the upper and lower CI do not change. So why do we need the vector of weights? Or is it that I am grossly or conceptually confused by the "vector of weights"?

e.g.

```
x<-c(0.51066)
se<-c(0.06334)
weight<-c(1.00)
par.avg(x, se, weight, level = 0.95, revised.var=T, adjusted = T)

Coefficient          SE Adjusted SE    Lower CI    Upper CI 
  0.5106600   0.0633400          NA   0.3865159   0.6348041
```

Changing the weight

```
x<-c(0.51066)
se<-c(0.06334)
weight<-c(0.60)
par.avg(x, se, weight, level = 0.95, revised.var=T, adjusted = T)


Coefficient          SE Adjusted SE    Lower CI    Upper CI 
  0.5106600   0.0633400          NA   0.3865159   0.6348041
```

Am I on the right track of interpreting confidence intervals from the par.avg() function?

Another question, if there is a single best model (w = 0.96), can we use the par.avg to find the confidence intervals from the standardized model coefficients?

Answer (score 1):

Weights, and averaging, make sense only for >1 parameters (each from one of the component models, not the averaged one, as I suppose you did in your example). You ask to "average" a single parameter so your weight is normalized to sum to 1.

If what you want is CI for the averaged parameters, use `confint`.

Comment: In case we have two factors (SU and SE) in a model and one of the factor (SU) is a subset in the next model (SU only) and we model average. Then for the factor SE, confint () gives values which are based on coefficients of the conditional average. However, for reporting model averaging should we not use the full model averaged coefficients to calculate confidence intervals? Since these two values differ for the factor SE, CI's follow:                                                    
-0.001326544  0.1822750 (cond)    -0.05985554  0.16381554 (full)

Comment: My comment is for use of the call for calculating CI. While confint () uses the conditional average, par.avg gives CI based on full model averaged coefficient values.

Comment: Use `confint(..., full = TRUE)`. The default conditional average remains only for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Got it. It worked.                                                                                               
This was an interesting exercise for me. I tried your suggestion confint(..., full = TRUE)., and the results were same as par.avg ().